# javascript keypress multiple records problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask why it will have multiple response?  How can i enter the input field with just one response?

Expectation : Input the data in input field and press the enter , it will execute the actions.

```js
$("#textInput").keypress(function (e) {

  console.log("123");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='textInput'/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery keypress event fires repeatedly when key is held - but not on all keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098168/jquery-keypress-event-fires-repeatedly-when-key-is-held-but-not-on-all-keys)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You have syntax error in you code. closing should be `});` instead of `)};`

```js
$("#textInput").keypress(function (e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input.

— jQuery Documentation [link](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

What you really want is `.submit()` as they are the one that will only be triggered when the user submits info.

```
$("#textInput").submit(function (e) {

console.log("123");
)};
```

Or if you only want to detect enter keypress but not submit, use this:
[How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should have choose other event,like `onblur` to fix your problem

```
$("#textInput").on('blur',function (e) {

  console.log("123");
)};
```

In your code ,`keypress` events gives you output,in every keypress action,So this is the reason you got multiple responses

And next,if you think,if you want to press `Enter` button then need response,In this case little changes will helps you

```
    $("#textInput").keypress(function (e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
        console.log("123");
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Expectation : Input the data in input field and press the enter , it will execute the actions.

In order to submit the corresponding form as soon as the user enters a text string and a final enter key you can:

- test if current char is the enter key (e.which == 13)
- get the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) form
- [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) the form

```js
$("#textInput").on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="/action_page.php">
    Enter text and type enter to submit:<br>
    <input type="text" name="textInput" value="">
</form>
```